# Android: Web Services using Soap

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have tried to login my server with some fields like username, password, latitude, longitude. Already i got registered. but while entering those fields i am getting server response as 06-18 09:02:14.402: VERBOSE/TAG(275): LoginResponse{LoginResult=-1; } that means it is missing some filds it is saying... can anyone plz check what is wrong in my code? This is my code...

```
package com.soap;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Register extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

// static Spinner operator = null;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
private static final String URL = "My Server Link";
private static final String TAG = "HELLO";

Thread t;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);
    Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logsigninbutton);

    signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0: {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait while connecting...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }
    }
    return null;
}

public void register() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;

    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    request.addProperty("email", "raghavang.srinivasg1988@gmail.com");
    request.addProperty("pwd", "ramg");
    request.addProperty("latitude", 72);
    request.addProperty("longitude", 86);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        androidHttpTransport
                .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
        String resultData;
        resultData = request.getProperty(0).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is reporting that you are missing some fields check the headers or other multi-part pieces to ensure you are including the entire structure your server is expecting.  What happens when you hit this endpoint using a desktop client versus Android?  Same thing?

Comment: Not without knowing allot more ... essentially through hitting the endpoint myself.  I do web service calls all the time from Android, but I handle my own XML document logic - no SoapObjects - and I use either HttpURLConnection or HttpClient classes for my communcations instead ... either work fine for GETs, POSTs, web services in general, etc., etc.

Comment: can u show me some examples regarding a clear procedure for doing web services in android...